# What is the difference between Windows Phone 8 OS and Windows Phone 8 Amber OS?

Tags: 8.0, update

Please tell me what is the major difference between Windows Phone 8 and Amber, because I want to update my device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amber is an update exclusive to Nokia devices.

[List of changes](http://conversations.nokia.com/2013/08/15/green-light-for-lumia-amber/):

- Improved image processing
- FM radio support
- Glance screen feature
- Flip to silence, double tap to wake
- Improved storage check, faster HERE map updates

[More details](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/18176_In_depth_guide_to_whats_new_in.php)

Comment: So that means in HTC device, I cant update Amber?

Comment: That's correct. You might however (depending on your phone carrier) get the general GDR2 update. For a list of improvements check here: http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-gdr2

Comment: Actually the correct is to say that every Windows Phone 8 can receive GDR2. Then the OEM personalize it like they want. Nokia called this AMBER. HTC version of GDR2 is enabling radio too but they didn't give a different name.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Akid's answer, the Amber update allows an instant boot up of the device once plugged in to a charger if the battery is totally drained, unlike before when you had to wait up to 10 minutes before it turns on. IMHO this is a very important improvement.